# Как задать разный цвет точек линии chartingToolkit:LineSeries в Chart?

Tags: wpf, диаграммы

Есть график chartingToolkit:Chart и на нем есть линия с точками chartingToolkit:LineSeries.
Вопрос: как можно в зависимости от значения объекта колекции привязанной к ItemSource раскрашивать точки в разные цвета(черный и красный)? 
Код и скриншот ниже.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="Chart1"    Title="{x:Static helper:UIHelper.KartaX}" MinHeight="205"  >
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="visualizationToolkit:Legend">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="visualizationToolkit:Title">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,-10" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
                <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes >
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis  Orientation="x" Minimum="{Binding MinRange}" Maximum="{Binding MaxRange}" Interval="1"/>
                    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis  Orientation="Y" Minimum="{Binding MinXY}" Maximum="{Binding MaxXY}" />
                </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>

   <chartingToolkit:LineSeries  ItemsSource="{Binding ChartDetailList}" 
                         IndependentValuePath="SampleId" DependentValuePath="XMeasure"  >
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle >
                          <Style TargetType="{x:Type chartingToolkit:LegendItem}">
                              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                          </Style>
                      </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.LegendItemStyle>
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="10" />
                        </Style>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
                            </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если нужно покрасить только точки, то можно написать триггер на изменение цвета в зависимости от значения. Контрол как таковой не видел, но WPF в целом дает такую возможность.

Comment: Триггер, то написать можно, только какое свойство изменяет, только цвет точек? Я что-то такого не нашел и цвет точек всегда такой же, как и цвет линии.

Comment: https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ - вот этим можно посмотреть из чего отрисован контрол.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, полезный инструмент, но вопрос пока ещё актуален

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во общем сам решил вопрос, добавив тригер:

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
    <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="10" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XAlarm, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XAlarm, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
```

Конвертер:

```
public  class ValueToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if ((string)value == "0" )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Теперь точки перекрашиваются на линии, если true, то в красный цвет, иначе в черный.

Спасибо, Monk, за инструмент помогло решить задачу.

Comment: Отметьте потом ваш ответ как верный (такая возможность появится через несколько дней).

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет